# use local postgres database to docker container

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Hey everyone i am trying to connect my postgres database install in ubuntu 20.04 to the docker container, which will be outside of the container. I am working on django project.

I am able to create the postgres database inside the docker container and connect my django project to that database, but i want is to connect localdatabase to the django project which is running in docker container

Here is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  # Description (For the postgres databse)
  kapediadb:
    image: postgres

    restart: always

    container_name: kapediadb
    # For accessing env data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}

  # Description (For django applications)
  kapedia:

    restart: always

    container_name: kapedia

    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        python manage.py makemigrations  accounts
        python manage.py makemigrations  posts
        python manage.py makemigrations  quiz
        python manage.py migrate
        gunicorn kapedia.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000


    image: kapedia

    # Description (define your dockerfile location here)
    build: .

    volumes:
      - .:/kapedia

    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

    depends_on:
      -   kapediadb

    env_file:
      - .env

# Description (For volumes)
volumes:
  static:
```

Comment: What's happening after running this container

Comment: it's running fine but i am not able to find the database. what i am trying is to connect my local database to the container

Comment: Means, you are not able find its database file

Comment: yes also i think my database is inside the docker container

Comment: Thanks but my my main question is can i connet my local database direclty to the docker container. like we use to connect postgres database before using docker

Comment: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) seems to discuss this at length; do the network setups there work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply you can add this inside project container:

```
extra_hosts:
   - "host.docker.internal:172.17.0.1"
```

To find IP of docker i.e. 172.17.0.1 (in my case) you can use in local machine's terminal:

```
$> ifconfig docker0
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
```

In `postgresql.conf,` change listen_addresses to `listen_addresses = '*'`

In `pg_hba.conf`, add this at the end of line

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

Now restart `postgresql` service using, `sudo service postgresql restart`

Please use `host.docker.internal` hostname to connect database from Server Application.

Ex: `jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5432/bankDB`

Note: `sudo nano /etc/postgresql/<your_version>/main/postgresql.conf` use this command to open `postgresql.conf` file

This is the way you can connect your local database to docker-contaner

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was running the docker container that was going to connect to the database using the `--network="host"` option in the `run` command:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --network="host" --name metabase metabase/metabase
```

The important part is the `--network="host"`, wich is explained in depth here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings